# ComboBox: Items would not be available once selected and entered

Tags: vba, combobox

I am planning to create a form for scheduling interviews. Ideally, I would want the chosen time to be deleted on the ComboBox once it had been chosen by the previous entry.

Example: First user picked "10am" for his schedule, then that schedule would be listed in a column. Then, Second user would no longer be able to see/pick "10am" for a schedule.

Thanks in advance for anyone who could help! Cheers!

Comment: Do you have a sample code? or Do you cope up with something that could help others to understand? maybe if you have, please attached it in your question.

Comment: Is this a Userform?  A Worksheet with a "Submit" button on it?  A Worksheet where you enter each interview into a row manually?  (The first two should be fairly similar, the third would need a completely different solution)

Comment: @Chronocidal Hi sir, i plan to have it in a User Form. Upon clicking 'Submit' button, the data would be encoded on a worksheet (this would include the chosen time for the schedule). Then, when there would be another user to encode new data for schedule, I want the previous Time chosen by the previous user would no longer be available in the combobox. this time.

Comment: @AlexisVillar, Hi sir, unfortunately, I do not have a code that I could come up with since I am just a beginner with VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Subroutine that will replace the List in a ComboBox object based on a Full List of Items, and a list of Items to exclude:

```
Private Sub RebuildItemList(ByRef ComboBox As Object, ByVal ItemsAvailable As Range, ByVal ItemsUsed As Range)
    'ComboBox: The ComboBox you want to change the list for
    'ItemsAvailable: A Range of cells that contain all the possible Items
    'ItemsUsed: A Range of cells that contain the Items you want to exlude from the list

    ComboBox.Clear 'Delete existing Entries

    If ItemsAvailable Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'No Items available

    If ItemsUsed Is Nothing Then 'All Items available
        ComboBox.ControlSource = ItemsAvailable.Address(True, True, xlA1, True)
    Else
        Dim WorkingRange As Range

        For Each WorkingRange In ItemsAvailable.Cells 'Check each Item
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ItemsUsed, WorkingRange.Value) < 1 Then
            'If Item has not yet been used
                ComboBox.AddItem WorkingRange.Value 'Add Item to the list
            End If
        Next WorkingRange
    End If
End Sub
```

For example, if you had a list of Times stored in the range `Sheet1.Range("A1:A20")`, and you stored your booked appointments in `Sheet2`, with the Time in Column C (i.e. `Sheet2.Columns(3)`) then you would replace the list in the ComboBox `ComboBox1` by like this:

```
RebuildItemList ComboBox1, Sheet1.Range("A1:A20"), Sheet2.Columns(3)
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks, mate! But I would like to ask if it is possible if it would based on another criteria? For example, Column E contains a list of rooms (Room 1, Room 2,..), If all time has been selected for Room 1 (say, 1:00 PM), then the items would no longer be available, but would still be available for Room 2 (1:00 PM) since the time has not yet been selected.

Comment: @Allen Yup, just change the `If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(WorkingRange.Value, ItemsUsed) < 1 Then` line - it sounds like you probably want a [`CountIfs` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)?

Comment: Hello, yes I would want to use a CountIfs function. There would be two columns that would be included on the argument (Column A and Column B). How should I add it with the code: If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(WorkingRange.Value, ItemsUsed) < 1 Then?

Comment: I would like to ask also - Where should I include the Subroutine Code? Should it be part of the CommandButton in the UserForm, or should it be part of the code within the ComboBox object?

Comment: @Allen You can use the [`Range.Offset` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset) to look at a cell Relative to the current Range (e.g. `ItemsUsed.Offset(0,1)` is the column to the Right of `ItemsUsed`).  The link in my last comment explains how `COUNTIFS` works, and gives some examples

Comment: Hi, I can't seem to understand where should I put the subroutine code; should it be part of the code in the CommandButton? Another thing is where should I put the code "RebuildItemList ComboBox1, Sheet1.Range("A1:A20"), Sheet2.Columns(3)"?

Comment: As a `Private Sub`, the code needs to go in the same Module that it is being called in.  (A `Public Sub` can be called from anywhere in the workbook)  Calling it can be done either in the `UserForm_Initialize` event, or in the Button press event, or the `UserForm_Activate` event - basically, **any** point *after* the UserForm is created, but *before* you open the DropDown.  (If you are able to book multiple appointments without closing the form, you will want to re-call it after you create each appointment)

Comment: Hi @Chronocidal, I have put the code `RebuildItemList ComboBox1, Sheet1.Range("F1:F10"), Sheet1.Range("C1:C10")` at the `UserFrom_Initialize` Event, but when run, the ComboBox does not show any items

Comment: Hi @Chronocidal, Thanks it was just my own mistake that's why list was not showing! It is working now. I would like to ask though, how could i fix the ComboBox list, since it is showing decimal values instead of the time?

Comment: @Allen If the Date is included in the cell value then it should copy the cell formatting, otherwise use `Format(WorkingRange.Value, "hh:mm")` when you add it to the List (and remember to use `cDate` to change back from Text to Date on the Output!)

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I'm a bit confused, at which line should I include the `Format(WorkingRange.Value, "hh:mm")` code? Should it be included after the `Next WorkingRange`?

Comment: sorry my mistake again. It works perfectly now. Though, I would like to ask one final question: could it be possible that the `RebuildItemList` subroutine will run only if the text written to the `TextBox` is the same as the Date today, else, the list in `ComboBox` would still be complete?

Comment: @Allen Change the `If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ItemsUsed, WorkingRange.Value) < 1 Then` line from `CountIf` to `CountIfs`, and include a "Date" condition based on your data - this will probably mean adding new `DaysUsed` and `DaysAvailable` parameters

Comment: Thank you for that. With the `DaysAvailable` should I store the dates? I was thinking that the available days would be any dates after today (e.g October 19, 20,...)

Comment: @Allen To be perfectly honest, that's something I can't answer - it will depend on how you are storing the data, and what your UserForm looks like.  If you first select "Date", and then select "Time" from another combo-box, then it will just be 1 value, and re-call `RebuildItemList` after you select the Date.  If you want both Date and Time in the same drop-down, that would require different code.

Comment: Thank you for that. My UserForm has a `TextBox` and `ComboBox` which will be used for the appointment. The `ComboBox` is where the `RebuildItemList` would be called, while the `TextBox` may have any value. I was thinking if it may be possible that if the Date entered on the `TextBox` is different from the date Today, then the list on the `ComboBox` would have the complete/incomplete list based on the stored data on `DaysUsed`.